# C++ if else statements does not display the correct values

Tags: c++

I am supposed to let the user input their purchase price to find out the shipping charge. The problem I am having is that if I input any value higher than $1,000, the shipping value will always be $8.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double saleAmount, shipping = 0;


    cout << "Enter a purchase amount to find out your shipping charges." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of your purchase: $" << endl; cin >> saleAmount; 

    if (saleAmount > 5,000.00)
    {
        shipping = 20.00; 
    }

     else if (saleAmount > 1,000.00)
     {
        shipping = 15.00;
    }
```

This is where it does not recognize the shipping above $10.00. If I enter 1,500 on the console app, it will always tell me the shipping charge is $10. Same goes for any value above $5,000. I tried to see what was the problem but I can't find it for the life of me.

```
    else if (saleAmount > 500.00)
    {
        shipping = 10.00;
     }
    else if (saleAmount > 250.00)
    {
        shipping = 8.00;
    }
    else
    {
        shipping = 0.00;
    }

    if (shipping == 0.00)
    {
        cout << "Error incorrect input" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The shipping charge on a purchase of $ " << saleAmount << " is $" << shipping << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't put commas in numbers in C.

Comment: Numbers don’t contain commas `,`.

Comment: FWIW, from C++14 [Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a separator, they are ignored by the compiler.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Comment: I see that now. Nice note to keep in handy. Taking out the commas and the programming works as intended. I guess my pseudocode had me stumped as I put commas in there. Will change.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
if (saleAmount > 5,000.00)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( (saleAmount > 5) , 000.00)
```

It evaluates to

```
if ( 0.000 )
```

Hence, the block of code under the `if` statement never gets executed.

As has been pointed to out in the comments, remove the `,` from the numbers. Use:

```
if (saleAmount > 5000.00)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most serious problems with this code are on these lines:

```
 if (saleAmount > 5,000.00)
 else if (saleAmount > 1,000.00)
```

When I compile your program with GCC and all the warnings turned on, these lines produce the following message:

```
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect
```

Do you understand what the problem is now?

Answer (score 2):

Remove , from 5,000 and 1,000 and it should work.

```
if (saleAmount > 5000.00)
else if (saleAmount > 1000.00)
```